# Proof of Master theorem for Case-1: How these steps are mathematically derived?

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

I was reading Thomas H. Cormen book to understand the Proof of Master theorem.However, i am stuck at proving case-1.please help me to understand the mathematical proofs by more easy  mathematical derivation of steps in the following image:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Two formulas are used: b^(log_b(a)) = a and the second one is the standard sum of geometric progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

```
b^{\log_b(a)} = a
```

(Don't we have TeX in SO?)

This is because the logarithm to the base `b` is the inverse of `b^`.
Then `a / a = 1`, thus only `b^epsilon` remains.

Second and third question: This is the geometric series, you can find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula
For this the summand `b^epsilon` must be between zero and one (exclusive), i.e. `|b^epsilon| < 1`.

Comment: thanks @Zabuza.However, can please explain **logarithm to the base b is the inverse of b^** with example? thanks

Comment: Of course. The standard logarithm known from school is to the base 10. It is the inverse of `10^`. Thus `log(10^5) = 5` and `10^(log(5)) = 5`. You can try it with a calculator :) Okay, we may want to be able to change the base of the *school logarithm*. We then write `log_b` for the logarithm to the base `b`, it analogously reverses `b^`. For example, `log_e` is the logarithm to the base of `e`, `ln` abbreviates it. The logarithm itself simply is defined as the inverse of its base. There is no explicit formula, it is so per definition. You may read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm :)